# Firebase single value event listener doesn't return

Tags: java, android, firebase

I've been using Firebase in my app successfully for several months. I just finished updating to use the 9.0.0 version, and I have one issue left that I can't figure out.

In my MainActivity onCreate function I check to see if the user is logged in to Firebase. If the user is logged in, then I attempt to fetch the user object that I have in my database.

This is the only instance in the app where i'm having trouble with this. I have verified that the user is signed in, and the DatabaseReference pointed to the right url.

The DatabaseReference is created, and the listener is added, but nothing on the listener ever fires...

```
    FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    if (auth != null && auth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
        DatabaseReference userRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(USERS).child(auth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
        userRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                // Logic for success is here...
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                // Logic for failure is here...
            }
        });
    }
```

Any ideas about what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: is it ever going into that if block? did you step through it?

Comment: Yep. I stepped through it and added log statements. It enters the if statement, it creates the DatabaseRef, and then the listener just never fires.

Comment: What kind of authentication are you using?? it seems there is an issue with custom authentication...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an issue with your project configuration that causes Firebase Auth tokens to not refresh properly. You need to add SHA-1 fingerprints for your apps in the Firebase console.

Go to the overview page of the project in the Firebase Console. Select the settings overflow menu of the app in question, and click "Manage". There will be a button to add SHA-1 values.

You can get SHA-1 values for your app by following the steps in [this guide](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth). You may need to re-download and add the google-services.json file to your app in Android Studio again, but I did not.

This similar [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37624843/6398321) as answered by a Firebase team member contains more details if you require.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not authenticating the user via any method you need to change the rules to

```
{
    "rules": {
        ".read": "auth == null",
        ".write": "auth == null"  
    }
}
```

to ensure that authentication is not required in order to access DB.