# Firebase change data from server, listen on Android

Tags: android, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm playing with Firebase. Updating data in server with node.js:

```
var db = firebase.database()
var ref = db.ref("game")
ref.update({
    "state": "state",
    "counter": counter
})
```

The data in Firebase console updated without problem but in Android, I can't retrieve any change. I want to listen "game" node's changes but no luck.

```
DatabaseReference database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference ref = database.child("game");

ref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        Log("1");
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        Log("2");
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Log("3");
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        Log("4");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log("5");
    }
});
```

There is no log in console.

Also, with `ValueEventListener` I'm still not seeing any change or error:

```
DatabaseReference ref = database.child("game");

ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Log("1");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log("2");
    }
});
```

I'm clearly doing something wrong. How can I listen the data changes in FireBase?

Comment: I'm not sure what isn't working. Is none of the Logs being written? Also, you're probably looking for a ValueEventListener: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/retrieve-data#value_events

Comment: I can't get any change or error event from firebase. There is no log. I also tried with ValueEventListener but I guess I am missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I 'solved' the issue by re-logging by user. I guess this is a bug.

Relevant: [Firebase single value event listener doesn't return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37473145/firebase-single-value-event-listener-doesnt-return)